# Can I update my sources.list after distribution upgrade of Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, software-sources

I've recently upgraded my Ubuntu desktop from 16.04 Xenial Xerus to 17.04 Zesty Zapus. But, my sources.list still has all entries for Xeniel version.

Eg: `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted`

Can I update all entries with `xeniel` to `zesty` in sources.list?
Will it cause any problems? What's the proper way?

Comment: what did you do to upgrade ubuntu ? the dist-upgrade option does not upgrade ubuntu , thus your sources did not change.

Comment: Software updator shown me a prompt if I should update to 17.04. I clicked `yes` and now my `About this computer` says version `17.04`.

Comment: I am not sure then. 17.04 is beyond end of life so that may have caused a problem.

Comment: Actually, I've upgraded it one month ago. Heavy downloads took place and lots of new packages were installed. There were no errors though during the upgrade.

Comment: Well, generally the advice is to upgrade to a supported release, so I might suggest you upgrade to 17.10 and then 18.04 when it is available. Note there are a lot of changes starting with 17.10